# R: Update input-variable in a function

Tags: r, function, statistics, lapply

How do i update a input variable of a function

```
df1 = data.frame(State = c('Arizona AZ','Georgia GG', 'Newyork NY','Indiana IN','Florida FL'), Score=c(62,47,55,74,31), id=c(1,2,3,4,5))
df1

df2 = data.frame(State = c('Arizona AZ','Georgia GG', 'Newyork NY','Indiana IN'), Score2=c(10,7,5,4), id=c(1,2,3,4))
df2
```

```
CalcPerc <- function(x, ins) {
  
  # 1) Subset + cbind
  y  <- subset(ins, id %in% x$id)
  
  z <- merge(x, y, by = c('State', 'id'))
  
  x1 <- 100*(z$Score2/z$Score)
  
  # Output - write in new col of x (input variable)
    print(x1)
    x$Percent <- x1 # Not working
}

CalcPerc(x= df2, ins = df1)
```

Is there a proper way to add a col to the input df and updating the input variable?

Thx for your help!

Comment: Do you just want to return x like this: `return(x)`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
library(dplyr)    
CalcPerc <- function(x, ins) {
      
    x %>% 
      left_join(ins %>% filter(id %in% x$id), by =  c('State', 'id')) %>% 
      mutate(Percent = round(Score2/Score*100,2)) %>% 
      pull(Percent)
    }
      
    CalcPerc(x= df2, ins = df1)
```

which gives you

```
[1] 16.13 14.89  9.09  5.41
```

Without the `pull` function the result would look like this

```
CalcPerc(x= df2, ins = df1)
       State Score2 id Score Percent
1 Arizona AZ     10  1    62   16.13
2 Georgia GG      7  2    47   14.89
3 Newyork NY      5  3    55    9.09
4 Indiana IN      4  4    74    5.41
```

Comment: However it does´t (auto)update the (given) variable in the environment